# React does not trigger rerender if you assign state value to another variable and then change the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

I stumbled upon a strange behaviour due to my lack of knowledge and experience.
I have a Component called inside another, looking like this:

```
            <CustomSelectionButtons
              values={roleTypes}
              label="Roles:"
              onSelect={setUserRoles}
              selected={roles}
            />
```

**roles** is a state variable, which is set with the onSelect method (setUserRoles).
Here it is:

```
  const setUserRoles = (button: AccountsAndRolesUnion) => {
   const updatedRoles: AccountsAndRolesUnion[] = roles; //this is the state variable.

   /* doing something with the local **updatedRoles** array */

   setRoles(updatedRoles);
  };
```

If I use the code like this, the component does not rerender after setRoles hook call.
However, If I assign the local variable with roles.slice(), everything works as expected, the component is rerendered.
So, this works:

```
const setUserRoles = (button: AccountsAndRolesUnion) => {
  const updatedRoles: AccountsAndRolesUnion[] = roles.slice(); //slicing the state variable.

  /* doing something with the local **updatedRoles** array */

  setRoles(updatedRoles);
};
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) creates a shallow copy of the original array, meaning that it returns a different object than `roles` itself, even though its content may be the same.

When you do `setRoles(roles)`, you are actually sending the exact same object in memory, and when React compares the props before deciding whether to re-render, it doesn't detect any difference. However, when you do `setRoles(roles.slice())`, you pass a different variable in memory, so React figures there is a change in props and re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `const updatedRoles=roles` creates another name for the exact same object in memory, so everything you do with `updatedRoles` is reflected in `roles`, in other words you mutate the state. `roles.slice()` on the other hand creates a new independent object. When you pass this new object to `setState` React can see the difference and trigger re-render, but when you just pass it `roles` by another name, React doesn't see any need to do anything because `updatedRoles` and `roles` are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you use the same array instance to update the state.
React checks only shallow equality. It's not iterating over the items.
`.slice()` creates a new array.
Always create a new array if your state is an array.